# Android Spinner Selected Item

Tags: android, spinner, android-cursor

I am populating a spinner from the database like this

```
    // Populating the City Spinner
    Cursor cities = db.cityList();
    startManagingCursor(cities);

    // create an array to specify which fields we want to display
    String[] from = new String[] { DBAdapter.KEY_NAME };
    // create an array of the display item we want to bind our data to
    int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

    Spinner cityList = (Spinner) this.findViewById(R.id.citySpiner);
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cities, from, to);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    cityList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When i try to get the content from the selected item of the spinner like this

```
// Get the City
                Spinner getCity = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.citySpiner);
                String cityName = getCity.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

i get the following. 
Is there a way i can get the city name or the city id from the database.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think, as you are using a customadapter and giving three lists in adapter...

you can't get the selected text simply by calling the getSelectedItem()..

Use this:

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewbyId(R.id.spinner);
int position = mySpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
String Text = yourCityList[position].toString(); // dont know which list is holding the city list... 
// i didn't use any db in any of my app so cant tell you how can you get list... 
// leaving it to you... :)
```

Hope it helps....

Answer (score 5):

Just get the adapter from your spinner and get the string from the cursor

```
Cursor cursor = (Cursor) myAdapter.getItem(position);
String cityName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_NAME));
```

Comment: is there a way like in HTML to have the name and key value like in the option select options.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by key value

Comment: <select>
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">Saab</option>
</select>  like this. The display text is Car names but values are ids

Comment: This works great, thanks! I was just looking for a way to get the cursor-loaded spinner's selected value as String without having to do a listener on the spinner. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    s = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    SQLiteDatabase sqldb = db.openDataBase();
    Cursor cr = sqldb.rawQuery("select Name from employee",null);
    if (cr.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
        list.add(cr.getString(0).toString());
        Toast.makeText(this,cr.getString(0).toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ArrayAdapter <String> a= new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
         a.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
          s.setAdapter(a);
        } while (cr.moveToNext());

      }//urvesh patel
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I achieved it was like this:

You will have to cast the getItem() method to a cursor as it is essentially just returning a cursor rather than an individual row in the cursor which is annoying.

```
final Cursor cursor = (Cursor) yourSpinner.getAdapter().getItem( position );
```

Move the cursor to the first row

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

Now you can get the string from the cursor using the column name that matches table originally queried when setting your spinners adapter which was grabbed above using getAdapter()

```
final String selectedPartUUID = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( TABLE_COLUMN_NAME ) );
```

Hope this helps and would appreciate any feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!!

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "getSelectedItem=" + spinnerString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "getSelectedItemPosition=" + nPos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public List<String> GetTexts() {
            ArrayList<String> texts = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < mSpinnerList.size(); i ++) {
                int position = mSpinnerList.get(i).getSelectedItemPosition();
                Log.d("DATA_TO_BE_SEND:", tennisModelArrayList.get(position).getStatus());
                texts.add(mSpinnerList.get(i).getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
            }

            return texts;
        }
```