# How to get spinner string value on android?

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

I have created a spinner and the items of spinner comes from database. However, When I use

```
public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
        View view, int pos, long id) {
        typeOFBCard = contactSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
      // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

When I call this listener and try to pick the chosen string of the spinner i get a reference of the sglite something like:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@40535568
```

This is the return value of typeOfBCard.

However, on the spinner I can see normal string like "Work".

Here is how I initialized the spinner :

```
contactSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.contactSpinner);
    mobileText =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobileText);
    mDbHelper = new DbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();
    cursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllBusinessCards();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    context =this;

    contactSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
```

Comment: PLease add how the spinner is initialized.

Comment: What's your issue? Are you not getting the string? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818850/android-spinner-selected-item)

Comment: I have added the initilized part above. please have a look still looking for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How ever on the spinner I can see normal string like "Work"

That is because you configured an `Adapter` on the `Spinner`, and the `Adapter` is pulling data out of the Cursor to display.

> How to get spinner string value on android?

There is no "spinner string value". `Spinners` don't have strings. They have views. Those views might be instances of `TextView`, or they might be instances of `ImageView`, or they might be instances of a LinearLayout holding onto a `TextView` and an `ImageView`, or...

If you want to get data out of the `Cursor`, call `getString()` on the `Cursor`.

Answer (score 0):

Every row in a spinner is a view but it's also a value/object from your source.
Try

```
public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
    View view, int pos, long id) {
     // Parent == where the click happened. 
    typeOFBCard = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
  // Do nothing.
}
}
```