# Getting value of choosed option in Spinner

Tags: android, string, spinner

I want to get value of choosed option  in Spinner.
I know, I can get this from setOnItemSelectedListener, but I don't want to use this.
I have this:

```
String spinner1odp  = spinnerSubject.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

But result of this code is: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@40f828e8. I want to get String, not something like that :/

Comment: how do you fill your spinner? with which collection?

Comment: @LalitPoptani whatever method OP may use to fill spinner but if is spinner display the correct value (string) then should nothing wrong with his code

Comment: @KalpeshLakhani did I say that the OP is having something wrong in his code?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are popping up Spinner from database. 
So considering that you will have to get the selected index first and fetch the required data from the Cursor:

Code Snippet :

```
int position = mySpinner.getSelectedItemPosition(); 
Cursor cursor = (Cursor) myAdapter.getItem(position);
String myText = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME));
```

Further Reference : [Android Spinner Selected Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818850/android-spinner-selected-item)

Comment: its not mandatory to register the listener to get the selected value.

Comment: Yes buddy. But read the full sentence I wrote :). I misinterpreted the OP's question. So editing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> By using this code you can get...

String value= (String)spinnerSubject.getItemAtPosition(spinnerSubject.getSelectedItemPosition());

Comment: what is the problem in OP's way then?