# Get the selected item from spinner

Tags: android

I have follow what the rest had stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787809/get-spinner-selected-items-text). However, that seems to be a problem with my coding. Initially, my spinner should have shown the first item in the list when i first arrive at this activity but not it is just empty. Luckily the list is still there when i click on the spinner to make my selection. And also, after i have made my selection, the toast did not show up. I am not sure whether this is the cause of it as it pop out in the DDMS after i have make my selection:

```
09-07 06:30:06.470: WARN/InputManagerService(50): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@43cbe3b0
```

**Here is the coding for this activity:**

```
package android.wps;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class locationFinder extends Activity {

WifiPositioningServices wifiPositioningServices = new WifiPositioningServices();

ArrayList<Profile> profileList = new ArrayList<Profile>();
ArrayList<String> profileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> mapNames = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.locationfinder);

    String[] temp = wifiPositioningServices.GetAllProfileData();

    final Spinner profiles = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.profileList);

    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
            profileNames);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    profiles.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

    profiles.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int pos, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String test = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), test, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    //store all profile data into a ArrayList of Profile objects
    for(int i=0; i<temp.length; i++){
        String[] result = temp[i].split(",");
        Profile profile = new Profile();
        profile.setProfileName(result[0]);
        profile.setOwner(result[1]);
        profile.setMap(result[2]);
        profile.setVisible(result[3]);
        boolean visible = Boolean.valueOf(result[3]);
        if(visible){
            //if visible is true, then add profile name and mac filters into arraylist 
            profileNames.add(result[0]);
            for(int j=4; j<result.length; j++){
                profile.setMacFiltersList(result[j]);
            }
        }
        profileList.add(profile);
    }
}
```

}

**locationfiner.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout
android:id="@+id/widget0"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/txtPofile"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Profile:"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:layout_x="10px"
android:layout_y="12px"
>
</TextView>
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/profileList"
android:layout_width="245px"
android:layout_height="36px"
android:layout_x="70px"
android:layout_y="12px"
>
</Spinner>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/counter"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:layout_x="0px"
android:layout_y="32px"
/>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: the code part which you posted seems to be okay. So the error should be somewhere else...

Comment: hi @Nishant, i have updated my question with the coding.

Comment: Problem can occur because of if(visible) condition. comment out this condition and after that check your application.

Comment: if you are referring to that, is for use to decide whether i should add in data into the ArrayList of the profile object. Nothing to do with the ArrayList for the spinner. Or unless you are referring that this might actually be the one that is causing the visibility of the text?

Answer (score 0):

Strange. After i shifted this whole paragraph of for loop to the top, before the initialization code for the spinner, everything is alright now. Items are display in the spinner before/after selection and the toast did appear after selection had been made.

**The for loop which i am referring to**

```
 for(int i=0; i<temp.length; i++){
    String[] result = temp[i].split(",");
    Profile profile = new Profile();
    profile.setProfileName(result[0]);
    profile.setOwner(result[1]);
    profile.setMap(result[2]);
    profile.setVisible(result[3]);
    boolean visible = Boolean.valueOf(result[3]);
    if(visible){
        //if visible is true, then add profile name and mac filters into arraylist 
        profileNames.add(result[0]);
        for(int j=4; j<result.length; j++){
            profile.setMacFiltersList(result[j]);
        }
    }
    profileList.add(profile);
}
```