# How to get text view value of simple_spinner_dropdown_item

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, spinner

i am working on a android project where i have a spinner with array list and a adapter the spinner is working fine. but i need to get the value on the text view of this spinner and use to in the other activity. but for the view i am using a Default List view("simple_spinner_dropdown_item") , now how can i access this text view form the list

Comment: Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787809/get-spinner-selected-items-text

Answer (score 0):

Get your selected spinner data as:

```
String selTextInSpinner = (String)yourSpinner.getSelectedItem();
```