# Android Firebase - Change listview data from firebase based on spinner

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I'm trying to display certain data on my listview based on item selected from a spinner. [This is how the display page currently looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mLK1.png) It's reading all the data from the node. Because "Running" is selected on the spinner above, I want the list view to only show Running.

Here is the code i'm using to read all the data.

```html
 @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        //reading data to listview, every time its saved
        currentUserDB2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                cardiosList.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot cardioHistorySnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    Cardio cardio = cardioHistorySnapshot.getValue(Cardio.class);

                    cardiosList.add(cardio);
                }

                CardioHistoryList adapter = new CardioHistoryList(Cardio_History.this, cardiosList);
                ListViewCardioHistory.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Working code

```html
spinnerCardioHistory.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    String name = spinnerCardioHistory.getSelectedItem().toString();


                    currentUserDB2.orderByChild("detailCategory").equalTo(name).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            cardiosList.clear();
                            for (DataSnapshot cardioHistorySnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                Cardio cardio = cardioHistorySnapshot.getValue(Cardio.class);

                                cardiosList.add(cardio);
                            }
                            CardioHistoryList adapter = new CardioHistoryList(Cardio_History.this, cardiosList);
                            ListViewCardioHistory.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only the word `Running` to be displayed then do the following:

```
 String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
 FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
 DatabaseReference currentUserDB2=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Cardio").child(user.getUid());
 currentUserDB2.orderByChild("detailCategory").equalTo(text).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            cardiosList.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot cardioHistorySnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

               String category=cardioHistorySnapshot.child("detailCategory").getValue().toString();
                cardiosList.add(category);
            }

            CardioHistoryList adapter = new CardioHistoryList(Cardio_History.this, cardiosList);
            ListViewCardioHistory.setAdapter(adapter);
```

First you get the select texted that is in the spinner `String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();`

then you add it in the query `orderByChild("detailCategory").equalTo(text)` and then retrieve from the database and it will only add the word that is selected in the spinner which is "Running".

Comment: i used the spinner on selected item and added the reading code there instead, I have the working code above.

Comment: `String name = spinnerCardioHistory.getSelectedItem().toString();` this can work even if it was not in itemselectedlistener, refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5787902/7015400