# android studio java audio timer and change activity based on drop down options

Tags: java, android, android-studio, chronometer

I have a seek bar already to an audio file I have in my raw file with pause/play/stop functionality, but how would I also add "clock", for lack of a better word, that shows how much time remains, or how much has gone by already based on the audio too?

And on one of my activities, I have a drop down option with different times on it, 5,10,15 mins, how can I make it so that when the user chooses one of these options, a different audio plays or so that it goes to a separate activity page based on what the user chose?

Here is my current activity with the audio:

```java
public void play(View view){

        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    public void pause(View view){
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }

    public void stop(View view){
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
    }
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        seekbar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mixkit);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openNewActivity();


            }
        });
        seekbar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
        new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                seekbar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            }
        }, 0, 500);
        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
    }
```

And for my page with dropdown:

```java
Spinner spinner;
    Button startButton;
    Button returnButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
        spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.time, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        startButton = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openNewActivity();
            }
        });
        returnButton = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        returnButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                returnToMain();
            }
        });

    }
```

I've spent a long time googling and havent found anything regarding the clock, only how to implement a clock and timer, but not how to link it with the seekbar/audio file. I assume I could make a clock and find out how long audio is but I feel like there must be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

So separate into 2 parts:

#### Display time remaining and time elapsed of an audio file

So you have a timer that updates the `Seekbar` every half second :

```java
    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            seekbar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
        }
    }, 0, 500);
```

And you have set the [`OnSeekBarChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener), which is expected to be triggered whenever there is a progress change in `Seekbar`:

```java
    seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(i);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
```

So basically with the above, you are ready to have *clocks* displaying the time remaining and the time elapsed. As the `onProgressChanged()` of your `OnSeekBarChangeListener` should be triggered by your `Timer` periodically and therefore you can put some logic there to update your *clocks*:

```java
// You can define 2 more TextView to display remaining time and elapsed time
TextView tvRemainingTime = findViewById(R.id.tvRemainingTime);
TextView tvElapsedTime = findViewById(R.id.tvElapsedTime);
final int totalDuration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
seekbar.setMax(totalDuration);
// Hold the timer with a variable so that you can access it if necessary
Timer timer = new Timer();
// Change to run the Timer with a period of 1 second
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        seekbar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
    }
}, 0, 1000);

seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
        // As progress is in milliseconds, you can write a function to convert milliseconds into displaying time
        tvElapsedTime.setText(convertMillisecondsToTime(progress));
        tvRemainingTime.setText(convertMillisecondsToTime(totalDuration - progress));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
});
```

Function to convert milliseconds into displaying time (Or you should further enhance it if you would like to display more detailedly):

```java
private String convertMillisecondsToTime(int target) {
    // For example, 30000 should be displayed as 00:30 mm:ss
    int seconds = (target / 1000) % 60;
    int minutes = (target / 1000) / 60;
    return String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
}
```

---

#### Go to different Activity from different Spinner option

To get selected value of Spinner, you can simply do the following:

```java
String selectedTime = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

And of course you can get the value of Spinner by index or by another way. See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787809/get-spinner-selected-items-text).

So for your `openNewActivity()` function, you can check the `selectedTime` and open the corresponding Activity:

```java
private void openNewActivity() {
    String selectedTime = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    // For example, if the values showing on Spinner are "5 mins", "10 mins", "15 mins"
    if ("5 mins".equals(selectedTime)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityFiveMinutes.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if ("10 mins".equals(selectedTime)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityTenMinutes.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } ...
}
```

And don't forget to add your newly created Activity in **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```xml
...
        <activity android:name=".ActivityFiveMinutes" />
        <activity android:name=".ActivityTenMinutes" />
...
```